# Zoom does not start anymore on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

On Ubuntu 22.04 Zoom version 5.15.2.4260 (the latest) does not start any more.
When I start Zoom from a commandline I do not get any messages.

How Can I fix this problem?

Comment: you don't get messges, but does the program stay running, or does it just exit with no errors?

Comment: at some point I had to regularly pkill zoom before it would start again; maybe try that.

Comment: I have tought about that but ps -eg | grep did not give output

Comment: I found out that Zoom version 5.15.2 (4260) works with a Linux kernal 5.15.0-76-generic (I did a restore of mu OS). But after installing patches a got  a 5.19.0-1010-nividia-lowlatency. And With this kernel Zoom version 5.15.2 (4260) does not start. Although I now know when it crashes, it is not a solution for my, because I can not install any (security) patches. So I still open for a solution.